# Program to reverse characters in assembler

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have a problem with my program in assembler (NASM).
Program get from user string of characters and write them to array.
Next program have to reverse the characters by ascii code (a=z, b=y, c=x etc.).
My program reverse correct only first character from array.

For example:
when I write 'abcd', I get 'z=>?'.

Can you help me?

My procedure:

```
odwroc:
    MOV bx, TEKST
    MOV cx, 0

    looop:
        XOR ax, ax
        XOR dx, dx

        ADD ax, 122
        MOV dx, [bx]
        SUB ax, dx

        MOV dx, 25
        SUB dx, ax

        MOV ax, 122
        SUB ax, dx

        MOV [bx], ax

        INC bx
        INC cx

        CMP cx, 255
        JLE looop   

RET
```

And array definitione:

```
TEKST db 255
      db 0
      TIMES 256 db 36
```

Comment: The code is a little peculiar in it's handling of `ax` and `dx`, and the `xor ax,ax` is meaningless at the beginning since you then `mov ax,122`. But To me it looks like the code you show should be doing the right thing. Are you sure this is the code you ran? How are you displaying your string? I don't see any string terminator being applied, so if you just try to "print" the string using assembly, it's going to do odd things.

Comment: Post a working implementation. This snippet does not get input from user and store it in memory. Does the routine need to reverse contents of memory or just display in reverse?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> TEKST db 255
>   db 0
>   TIMES 256 db 36
> ```

Judging from how you defined the *TEKST*, I understand that the input was coming from DOS Buffered Input function 0Ah.
If this is indeed the case then the text will be stored at the adres `TEKST + 2`. You'll need to write `mov bx, TEKST + 2`.

The inputted string will rarely be 255 bytes long. Your loop should end when all the characters are processed. Change `cmp cx, 255` by `cmp cl, [TEKST+1]`.

The text is composed of characters that are exactly 1 byte each. All of your program treats them as words (2 bytes). That's clearly wrong.

---

This is your program with corrections. There's still room for improvements!

```
MOV bx, TEKST + 2
MOV cx, 0

looop:
    MOV al, 122    ;'z'
    SUB al, [bx]

    MOV dl, 25     ;'z' - 'a'
    SUB dl, al

    MOV al, 122    ;'z'
    SUB al, dl

    MOV [bx], al

    INC bx
    INC cx

    CMP cl, [TEKST + 1]
    JB  looop
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement @Sep Roland 's answer, here is another way, using `lea`, which should run faster:

```
table_rot:

db    0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7 \ 
      8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 \
     16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23 \
     24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31 \
     32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39 \
     40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47 \
     48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55 \
     56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63 \
     64, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84 \ ; 65 'A' becomes 90 'Z', decrements until 65 is reached
     83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76 \
     75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68 \
     67, 66, 65, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95 \
     96,122,121,120,119,118,117,116 \ ; 97 'a' becomes 122 'z', decrements until 97 is reached
    115,114,113,112,111,110,109,108 \
    107,106,105,104,103,102,101,100 \
     99, 98, 97,123,124,125,126,127 \

odwroc:
     lea     di, [rel table_rot]     ; remove 'rel' depending on OS
     mov     bx, TEKST + 2           ; assuming that the input was coming from DOS Buffered Input function 0Ah
     movzx   cx, byte [TEKST + 1]    ; counter, same DOS assumption 

looop:
     mov     al, byte[di + bx]   ; will load the byte corresponding to the table and add value of the current letter.
     mov     [bx], al            ; load value of AL register in BX current pointer location
     inc     bx                  ; increment bx pointer, ie: go to next letter
     dec     cx
     jnz     looop   
ret
```

I will let the care of improving the loop sequence to another developer.~
Also I haven't tested it so please let me know if I forgot anything.

Comment: For a limited demo like this where speed is likely not a priority you could use less space, make it simpler, and more readable by subtracting the lower numeric bounds eliminating the non-applicable areas and even use xlat if you wanted

Comment: Thank for pointing out the idea of using xlat. The current "less space, simpler, more readble" has already been answered. Also who said speed wasn't a priority ? It can have some cryptographic uses like salting a hash.

Comment: @AntoninGavrel Using 64-bit registers and working with an assumption about DOS, doesn't compute. I do like your idea about using a translation table, that's why I corrected the code and gave an upvote.